# Trying to make a IF(AND) statement work in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

I am trying to use an IF(AND statement in excel however it is not working properly. It seems one of the functions does work but the other one does not.

I have tried deleting the AND part of the formula and using only the IF however it still has the same problem.

The code I am using at the moment is:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIFS(F10:F15, "=<" & 2000) = 0, COUNTIFS(F10:F15, ">=" & 2000) = 0),  "All of the properties were constructed ", "The majority of properties were constructed ")
```

The main problem is that when all the data shows 2000 or above the formula still shows "the majority of the properties" when it should show "all of the properties". When the data is 1999 or less it does change to "All of the properties".

Basically if all values in F10:F15 are 2000 or above it should return "all of the properties were constructed" and if all the values are 1999 or below it should also return "all of the properties were constructed". Otherwise it should state "the majority of the properties were constructed".

Comment: Try changing `=<` for `<=`. That said. The condition, as currently written *cannot*, ever, return true. Can yo please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55801375/edit) to explain what the results should be?

Comment: It will only be true when the cells `F10:F15` are all blank, but I guess that would not mean that all the properties were constructed. Isn't it.

Comment: My apologies if that wasnt clear. Basically if all values in F10:F15 are 2000 or above it should return "all of the properties were constructed" and if all the values are 1999 or below it should also return "all of the properties were constructed". Otherwise it should state "the majority of the properties were constructed".

Answer (score 1):

So, based on your comment I think this will do what you expect:

```
IF(COUNTIFS(A2:A21, ">" & 2000)=COUNT(A2:A21),  "All of the properties were constructed ", "The majority of properties were constructed ")
```

See this showing both results:

[image]

Comment: I still get the same problem that when the values are all 2000 or above the function returns "the majority of the properties were constructed" and it should return "all of the properties were constructed" when all the values are 2000 or above and when all the values are 1999 or below.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I am expecting, thought the "=0" would do the trick but this makes more sense.